# Update javascript table: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tableRow'

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html-table

I'm making a contacts app that updates a table with the users input but can't seem to get the table to update once I input data I only get the error above. Not sure how what I've to change the method to, I've tried lots of different functions etc., but no luck.

```
var nameField, addressField, emailField, postcodeField;

function twoDigit(v){
if(v.toString().length < 2){
    return "0"+v.toString();
} else {
    return v.toString();
}
}

var Contact = function(name, address, email, postcode){
this.name = name;
this.address = address;
this.email = email;
this.postcode = postcode;
this.completed = false;
};

var contacts = [];

Contact.prototype.toString = function(){
var s = this.name + '\n' + this.address + '\n' + this.email + + '/n'
  +  this.postcode.toString() + '\n';
if(this.completed){
    s += "Completed\n\n";
} else {
    s += "Not Completed\n\n";
}
return s;
};

var addContact = function(nameField, addressField, emailField, postcodeField){
a = new Contact(nameField.value, addressField.value, 
emailField.value, postcodeField.value);
contacts.push(a);
};

var clearUI = function(){
var white = "#fff";
nameField.value = "";
nameField.style.backgroundColor = white;
addressField.value = "";
addressField.style.backgroundColor = white;
emailField.value = "";
emailField.style.backgroundColor = white;
postcodeField.value = "";
postcodeField.style.backgroundColor = white;

};

var updateList = function(){
var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table"),
    table = "<table border='1'><thead><th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th><th>Email</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Completed</th></thead>";

for(var i=0, j=contacts.length; i<j; i++){
    var contacts1 = contacts[i];
     table += contacts1.tableRow();
}
table+="</table>";
tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
};

var add = function(){
addContact(nameField, addressField, emailField, postcodeField);
clearUI();
updateList();
};

var cancel = function(){
clearUI();
updateList();
};

window.onload = function(){
nameField = document.getElementById("name");
addressField = document.getElementById("address");
emailField = document.getElementById("email");
postcodeField = document.getElementById("postcode");
okButton = document.getElementById("ok");
okButton.onclick = add;
cancelButton = document.getElementById("cancel");
cancelButton.onclick = cancel;
clearUI();
}; 

var showTable = function(){
var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table"),
    table = "<table border='1'><thead><th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th><th>Email</th>  <th>Postcode</th></thead>";

for(var i=0, j=contacts.length; i<j; i++){
    var contacts1 = contacts[i];
    table += contacts1.tableRow();
}
table+="</table>";
tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
};
```

Comment: Code is incomplete: what the contacts array is?

Comment: This code looks like a copy and paste gone wrong.... the first two statements and the last two statements appear as though you want to build a table by string concatenation, but the middle suggests you want to add rows via the dom.  Even though tableRow() would probably have to be changed to insertRow.  Even that's a assuming that contacts is a reference to a Table element.  Actually, contacts would have to be an array of table elements.... this code sample is awkward.